# Calling python modules from julia

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to call a set of python modules from a myfile.py file from the current directory in Julia using @pyimport macro from PyCall package. I am not very sure how to use the PyCall functions to do this.

Comment: Please could add some code to show what you already tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is stated in the readme of https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl that you can execute `unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")` to add current directory to search path.

Comment: When I use this, I get the error ERROR: UndefVarError: PyVector not defined

Comment: Have you remembered to execute `using PyCall` before the command?